# Triangle of particular size with Python turtle graphics

Tags: geometry, python-turtle

I am still quite new to Python and I would like to create a program which would draw geometry objects of given size. For example how would I create the triangle with the sides of 7cm, 6 cm and 5 cm? Any hint would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

do you want the sizes to be user inputted?
if you do, in my experience I created a loop with the colour and amount of rectangles they wanted by using `x=int(number)` then `for i in range(x):` this allowed the user to choose how many rectangles. Before hand I put in an input code to get the answer `print("how many rectangles do you want?")` and `number = input("I want this many rectangles:")`

Although it isn't the exact same, if you know what numbers equals what distance you want, then you could redo the `x=int(number)` for each side and instead move the x from the code i mentioned before to the moving codes. eg,`forward(x)`

I hope that helped, let me know if you don't understand